# Delete part of src after a certain character

Tags: php, wordpress, ifttt

I am using IFTTT with Wordpress, so every time that I create a post on instagram, the recipe creates a post on Wordpress.

**The code that IFTTT creates**:

```
<div>
   <img src='https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/12724750_1719815604930604_2078818546_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE5MTQxNTkwMjE5ODM2NzYwOQ%3D%3D.2' style='max-width:600px;' /><br/>
   <div>
      <a href="http://ift.tt/1XKFC24Q7" target="_blank">See</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

For some reason a plugin that I am using to add this image like featured image, doesn't like this end of the src of the image, so I need to **delete the code after ".jpg"**:

> "?ig_cache_key=MTE5MTQxNTkwMjE5ODM2NzYwOQ%3D%3D.2").

I've found a Wordpress filter that modify the post before save.
So I tried this code but this delete all the other code after the `?`

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' ,  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {

  $data['post_content'] = substr( $data['post_content'], 0, strpos( $data['post_content'], "?")); delete all after ?

  return $data;
}
```

How can say delete everything after the question mark (?) but **ONLY** inside the src of the img tag?

This is the reference for `$data['post_content']`:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Comment: Could you please add some further detail to the question. What exactly is in post_content? You may require a regex if you're looking to extract/replace a certain part of the code

Comment: I added more details

Comment: See my updated answer - does that do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all, I solved with this code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' ,  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace('/(\?.*)(?=\' style)/','', $data['post_content']);
    return $data;
}
```

but now I have another issue, how can I sayto  apply this filter **ONLY** if the category is "Instagram"?

this condition seems doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' ,  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {

  if ( in_category('instagram') ) {
    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace('/(\?.*)(?=\' style)/','', $data['post_content']);
    return $data;
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer to close the post. Don't ask new questions in answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to replace the content in that specific HTML then maybe try this:

```
$a="<div><img src='https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/12724750_1719815604930604_2078818546_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE5MTQxNTkwMjE5ODM2NzYwOQ%3D%3D.2' style='max-width:600px;' /><br/><div><a href='http://ift.tt/1XKFC24Q7'target='_blank'>See</a></div></div>";
echo preg_replace('/(\?.*)(?=\')/U','',$a);

<div><img src='https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/12724750_1719815604930604_2078818546_n.jpg' style='max-width:600px;' /><br/><div><a href='http://ift.tt/1XKFC24Q7'target='_blank'>See</a></div></div>
```

Good luck

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Does the regex resolve your problem? It may need some enhancement depending on the specific contents of your post_content variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I wrote that does that.

```
$string = "img src='https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/12724750_1719815604930604_2078818546_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE5MTQxNTkwMjE5ODM2NzYwOQ%3D%3D.2' style='max-width:600px;' /><br/>";
$string2 = "asd";
$count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
{
    if($string[$i]=='?')
    {
        while($string[$i]!='\'')
            $i++;
    }
    $string2[$count] = $string[$i];
    $count++;
}
echo $string2;
```

It will basically copy the contents of one string into another, but will skip anything following a `?` until it finds a `'`

It's up to you to implement it, should be pretty simple. The code I posted outputs

`img src='https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/12724750_1719815604930604_2078818546_n.jpg' style='max-width:600px;' />`

Bear in mind this code is designed for this task only, it will only work here, be careful what you use it for as it may produce unexpected results, if for example you have other question marks in the content.

However it would be much easier to edit the link before it becomes HTML, if it's a plugin that's fetching the link it shouldn't be very hard.